# Write lines from text file into .csv file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following code that creates a csv file (sw_mac_addr.csv).  Right now it writes each line that I want.  I need it to separate the values with a comma (,).

a single line from the infile looks like this:

`* 51       0000.0c9f.f033    static    0          F    F  sup-eth2`

I want it to appear in the csv file like this:

`51,0000.0c9f.f033,sup-eth2`

```
import os
path = 'c:/sw_mac_addr/'
fh = open("C:/Users/cslayton2/Documents/sw_mac_addr.csv", "w+")
print('Switch Name', 'Port', 'mac addr', 'vlan', sep=",", file=fh)

for filename in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith('*') or line.startswith('+'):
                fh.write(line)
fh.close()
```

Comment: Is there a good reason not to use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module in the standard library here (or maybe a third-party library like Pandas)? You _can_ write your own code that parses and builds CSV rows and gets all the quoting/escaping/etc. right, but why do you want to?

Comment: You should definitely look into using `csv` to both read `infile` and write `outfile`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using csv for other scripts.  I'll look into it.

Comment: If your fields don't contain embedded commasand you can do a simple split on `line`, you might even be able to get away with `print(*line.split(), sep=',', file=fh)` instead of `fh.write(line)` but using a `csv.writer` is definitely more robust.

Comment: and to note: `if line.startswith('*') or line.startswith('+')` can be written as `if line.startswith(('*', '+'))`... (or `if line.startswith(tuple('*+'))`...)

Comment: Please don't change your question to ask a different question - just ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas can do this well

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('c:/sw_mac_addr/mycsv.csv', sep=',')
df.to_csv('c:/sw_mac_addr/test.txt')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
path = './text/'
# open this file for writing
with open("sw_mac_addr.csv", "w+") as fh:
    print('Switch Name', 'Port', 'mac addr', 'vlan', sep=",", file=fh)
    # get data from all files in the path
    for filename in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path,filename), "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                if line.startswith('*') or line.startswith('+'):
                    # if you want to get rid of the * and +, uncomment the following code
                    # line = line.replace("*","").replace("+","")
                    line = ",".join(line.split()) + "\n"
                    fh.write(line)
                    print(line)
```

output (both on console and csv file):

```
*,51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2

*,51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2

*,51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2
```

output with uncommented line of code (line = line.replace("*";"").replace("+","")

```
51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2

51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2

51,0000.0c9f.f033,static,0,F,F,sup-eth2
```